# Getting time since epoch in milliseconds isn't outputting correctly

Tags: c++11, time, milliseconds, c++-chrono, system-clock

I've used the code from one of the answers on this forum but it's doesn't appear to be correct. I don't know if it's the code or the way I'm logging it.

```
unsigned long long int NQCTestInstance::getCurrentTimeInMs() {

    unsigned long milliseconds_since_epoch =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
        (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();

    Log("Timestamp = %u\n\n", milliseconds_since_epoch);

    return milliseconds_since_epoch;

}
```

The **Log** output is 119682234, which is only nine characters when it should be ten. Is this as simple as the **%u** in the Log statement being incorrect?

Comment: Try %lu........

Comment: You have a return type of `unsigned long long`, use a variable of type `unsigned long`, and use a format specifier suitable for `unsigned int`. Consider using `unsigned long long` throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Igor Tandetnik and @John Zwinck were on the right tracks.

I changed everything to `unsigned long long` and then used `%llu` (not `%lu`) for the logging.